# Count by range doesnt give desired output

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, routines

Im creating a routine to give me a output like

```
|  Row  |  Voters  | Households  |
| Total |  15235   |  7250       | 
| Poll  |  NULL    |   NULL      |
| <70%  |  5000    |   2500      |
| <80%  |  3500    |   2235      |
     .....
|  AV   |   NULL   |   NULL      |
| <70%  |   300    |  150        |
     .....
|  PAV  |   NULL   |   NULL      |
| <70%  |  1894    |  1201       |
```

All goes from <70% to <100%

I have a routine code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `district_Propensity_counts`(IN target INT)
    COMMENT 'build demographic table for district'
BEGIN

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Temp;

   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Temp (
      Row   VARCHAR(25)   DEFAULT NULL,
      Col   VARCHAR(15)   DEFAULT NULL,
      Data  MEDIUMINT(12) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
      Seq   TINYINT(2)    UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO Temp 
   SELECT 'Total' AS Row, 
          'Voters' AS Col, 
          COUNT(*) AS Data,
          1 as Seq 
     FROM VoterProfile p 
    INNER JOIN DistrictPrecinct d 
            ON d.precinct_id=p.precinct_code 
         WHERE district_id=target 
   UNION 
   SELECT 'Total' AS Row, 
          'Households' AS Col, 
          COUNT(HHKey) AS Data, 
          1 as Seq 
     FROM (SELECT HHKey 
             FROM VoterProfile p 
       INNER JOIN DistrictPrecinct d 
               ON d.precinct_id=p.precinct_code 
            WHERE district_id=target
                GROUP BY HHKey) AS A


UNION

SELECT 'Poll' AS Row,
NULL AS Col, NULL AS Data, 2 AS Seq



     UNION

    (
     SELECT r.Row
     , 'Voters' AS Col
     , CASE r.Row
         WHEN '< 70%' THEN IFNULL(d.c70,0)
         WHEN '< 80%' THEN IFNULL(d.c80,0)
         WHEN '< 90%' THEN IFNULL(d.c90,0)
         WHEN '< 100%' THEN IFNULL(d.c100,0)
       END AS Data
     , 3 AS Seq
  FROM ( SELECT '< 70%' AS Row
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 80%' 
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 90%'
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 100%' 
       ) r
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT SUM(vp.poll_propensity >= 0.70 AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.mail_propensity = 0) AS c70
              , SUM(vp.poll_propensity >= 0.80 AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.mail_propensity = 0) AS c80
              , SUM(vp.poll_propensity >= 0.90 AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.mail_propensity = 0) AS c90
              , SUM(vp.poll_propensity >= 1    AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.mail_propensity = 0) AS c100
              , COUNT(p.voter_id) AS count_voter_id
           FROM VoterProfile p
           JOIN DistrictPrecinct d ON d.precinct_id=p.precinct_code
           JOIN VoterPropensity vp ON p.voter_id=vp.voter_id
          WHERE d.district_id = target
            AND vp.election_type = 'T'
       ) d
 ORDER BY r.Row)



    UNION(
     SELECT r.Row
     , 'Households' AS Col
     , CASE r.Row
         WHEN '< 70%' THEN IFNULL(d.c70,0)
         WHEN '< 80%' THEN IFNULL(d.c80,0)
         WHEN '< 90%' THEN IFNULL(d.c90,0)
         WHEN '< 100%' THEN IFNULL(d.c100,0)
       END AS Data
     , 3 AS Seq
  FROM ( SELECT '< 70%' AS Row
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 80%' 
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 90%'
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 100%' 
       ) r
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT SUM(vp.poll_propensity >= 0.70 AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.mail_propensity = 0) AS c70
              , SUM(vp.poll_propensity >= 0.80 AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.mail_propensity = 0) AS c80
              , SUM(vp.poll_propensity >= 0.90 AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.mail_propensity = 0) AS c90
              , SUM(vp.poll_propensity >= 1    AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.mail_propensity = 0) AS c100
              , COUNT(p.HHKey) AS count_HHKey
           FROM VoterProfile p
           JOIN DistrictPrecinct d ON d.precinct_id=p.precinct_code
           JOIN VoterPropensity vp ON p.voter_id=vp.voter_id
          WHERE d.district_id = target
            AND vp.election_type = 'T'
            GROUP BY HHKey
       ) d
 ORDER BY r.Row)



 UNION
SELECT 'AV' AS Row,
NULL AS Col, NULL AS Data, 4 AS Seq                     


    UNION(
     SELECT r.Row
     , 'Voters' AS Col
     , CASE r.Row
         WHEN '< 70%' THEN IFNULL(d.c70,0)
         WHEN '< 80%' THEN IFNULL(d.c80,0)
         WHEN '< 90%' THEN IFNULL(d.c90,0)
         WHEN '< 100%' THEN IFNULL(d.c100,0)
       END AS Data
     , 5 AS Seq
  FROM ( SELECT '< 70%' AS Row
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 80%' 
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 90%'
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 100%' 
       ) r
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 0.70 AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.poll_propensity = 0) AS c70
              , SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 0.80 AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.poll_propensity = 0) AS c80
              , SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 0.90 AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.poll_propensity = 0) AS c90
              , SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 1    AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.poll_propensity = 0) AS c100
              , COUNT(p.voter_id) AS count_voter_id
           FROM VoterProfile p
           JOIN DistrictPrecinct d ON d.precinct_id=p.precinct_code
           JOIN VoterPropensity vp ON p.voter_id=vp.voter_id
          WHERE d.district_id = target
            AND vp.election_type = 'T'
       ) d
 ORDER BY r.Row)


    UNION(
     SELECT r.Row
     , 'Households' AS Col
     , CASE r.Row
         WHEN '< 70%' THEN IFNULL(d.c70,0)
         WHEN '< 80%' THEN IFNULL(d.c80,0)
         WHEN '< 90%' THEN IFNULL(d.c90,0)
         WHEN '< 100%' THEN IFNULL(d.c100,0)
       END AS Data
     , 5 AS Seq
  FROM ( SELECT '< 70%' AS Row
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 80%' 
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 90%'
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 100%' 
       ) r
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 0.70 AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.poll_propensity = 0) AS c70
              , SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 0.80 AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.poll_propensity = 0) AS c80
              , SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 0.90 AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.poll_propensity = 0) AS c90
              , SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 1    AND p.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.poll_propensity = 0) AS c100
              , COUNT(p.HHKey) AS count_HHKey
           FROM VoterProfile p
           JOIN DistrictPrecinct d ON d.precinct_id=p.precinct_code
           JOIN VoterPropensity vp ON p.voter_id=vp.voter_id
          WHERE d.district_id = target
            AND vp.election_type = 'T'
            GROUP BY HHKey
       ) d
 ORDER BY r.Row)



   UNION
SELECT 'PAV' AS Row,
NULL AS Col, NULL AS Data, 6 AS Seq 


    UNION(
     SELECT r.Row
     , 'Voters' AS Col
     , CASE r.Row
         WHEN '< 70%' THEN IFNULL(d.c70,0)
         WHEN '< 80%' THEN IFNULL(d.c80,0)
         WHEN '< 90%' THEN IFNULL(d.c90,0)
         WHEN '< 100%' THEN IFNULL(d.c100,0)
       END AS Data
     , 7 AS Seq
  FROM ( SELECT '< 70%' AS Row
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 80%' 
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 90%'
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 100%' 
       ) r
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 0.70 AND p.perm_absentee = 'Y') AS c70
              , SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 0.80 AND p.perm_absentee = 'Y') AS c80
              , SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 0.90 AND p.perm_absentee = 'Y') AS c90
              , SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 1    AND p.perm_absentee = 'Y') AS c100
              , COUNT(p.voter_id) AS count_voter_id
           FROM VoterProfile p
           JOIN DistrictPrecinct d ON d.precinct_id=p.precinct_code
           JOIN VoterPropensity vp ON p.voter_id=vp.voter_id
          WHERE d.district_id = target
            AND vp.election_type = 'T'
       ) d
 ORDER BY r.Row)



        UNION(
     SELECT r.Row
     , 'Households' AS Col
     , CASE r.Row
         WHEN '< 70%' THEN IFNULL(d.c70,0)
         WHEN '< 80%' THEN IFNULL(d.c80,0)
         WHEN '< 90%' THEN IFNULL(d.c90,0)
         WHEN '< 100%' THEN IFNULL(d.c100,0)
       END AS Data
     , 7 AS Seq
  FROM ( SELECT '< 70%' AS Row
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 80%' 
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 90%'
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 100%' 
       ) r
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 0.70 AND p.perm_absentee = 'Y') AS c70
              , SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 0.80 AND p.perm_absentee = 'Y') AS c80
              , SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 0.90 AND p.perm_absentee = 'Y') AS c90
              , SUM(vp.mail_propensity >= 1    AND p.perm_absentee = 'Y') AS c100
              , COUNT(p.HHKey) AS count_HHKey
           FROM VoterProfile p
           JOIN DistrictPrecinct d ON d.precinct_id=p.precinct_code
           JOIN VoterPropensity vp ON p.voter_id=vp.voter_id
          WHERE d.district_id = target
            AND vp.election_type = 'T'
            GROUP BY HHKey
       ) d
 ORDER BY r.Row
 )




     ;

END
```

then use a second procedure that call the first procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `district_propensity`(IN target varchar(30))
    COMMENT 'display demographics for district'
BEGIN

  CALL district_Propensity_counts(target);

  SELECT district_id, district_name FROM Districts WHERE district_id=target;

  SELECT Row,
         GROUP_CONCAT(IF (COL='Voters',Data,NULL))+0 AS 'Voters', 
         GROUP_CONCAT(IF (COL='Households',Data, NULL))+0 AS 'Households' 
    FROM Temp 
    GROUP BY ROW
    ORDER BY SEQ;


END
```

but the output i get when i do:

```
CALL district_propensity('3')
```

is something like

```
|  Row  |  Voters  |  Households  |
| Total |  15235   |    7250      |
| Poll  |  NULL    |    NULL      |
| <90%  |  4565    |     1        |
| AV    |  NULL    |     NULL     |
| <100% |  668     |     0        |
| <70%  |  1894    |     0        |
| <80%  |  1434    |     3        |
|  PAV  |  NULL    |     NULL     |
```

thats it... im missing all the others.. 
but the numbers in the voters column is correct..  its counting that right but missing a whole lot..

any help on this is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(IF (COL='Voters',Data,0))+0 AS 'Voters', 
GROUP_CONCAT(IF (COL='Households',Data,0))+0 AS 'Households'
```